# How to show pojo properties in TornadoFX tableview?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I'm writing a very simple TornadoFX table demo, trying to display the properties of some pojos in a table, but the cells are all empty.

The main code is:

```
data class User(val id: Int, val name: String)

private val data = listOf(User(111, "AAA"), User(222, "BBB"), User(333, "CCC"), User(444, "DDD")).observable()

class HelloWorld : View() {

    override val root = vbox {
        tableview(data) {
            column("id", User::id.getter)
            column("name", User::name.getter)
        }
    }
}
```

I use `User::id.getter` to make it compiling, but the cells are empty.

I did a lot of search, but can't find code to work with current latest tornado (`1.7.16`)

Here is a complete demo for this: https://github.com/javafx-demos/tornadofx-table-show-pojo-demo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference the property, not the getter, ie. `User::id`. To reference immutable properties you need to use the `readonlyColumn` builder:

```
readonlyColumn("id", User::id)
readonlyColumn("name", User::name)
```

That said, you really should use JavaFX properties in your domain objects instead. Not doing so in a JavaFX based application just makes everything harder, and you loose out on a lot of benefits, or at the very least you have to jump through hoops.

Here is the complete application written with observable JavaFX properties. Note that you would then access the `idProperty` and `nameProperty` properties instead. With this approach, changes to the underlying data item would automatically be visible in the tableview as well:

```
class User(id: Int, name: String) {
    val idProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(id)
    var id by idProperty

    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty(name)
    var name by nameProperty
}


private val data = listOf(User(111, "AAA"), User(222, "BBB"), User(333, "CCC"), User(444, "DDD")).observable()

class HelloWorld : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        tableview(data) {
            column("id", User::idProperty)
            column("name", User::nameProperty)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing `readonlyColumn` and all the sugguestions